# Links to HTML files in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, hyperlink, href

I need to show link to html file. The path to this file is root `folder/test/index.html`. I try using

```
$this->URL->build, href
```

but still no luck.

Comment: what code u mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your HTML files inside cakephp webroot folder.

```
webroot/
  index.php
  css/
  img/
  js/
  test/   <--- html content
   index.html
   other.html
```

build links:

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->link('LINK 1','/test/index.html');
```